# Multiview app creating new viewControllers each time I switch pages?

Tags: objective-c

I am using a navigation controller and pushing new view controllers to switch between a multipage Iphone application.As Follows;

```
- (IBAction)startButton:(id)sender{
    GoalViewController *thisGoalViewController = [[GoalViewController alloc] 
                                                  initWithNibName:@"GoalViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.goalViewController = thisGoalViewController;
    [thisGoalViewController release];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.goalViewController animated:YES ];
}
```

Everything works fine. But when I place a

```
 NSLog(@"Goal View ID: %p",self);
```

in the GoalViewController viewDidLoad method, I get a different value each time I switch pages.

In the GoalViewController, I am using this to pop back;

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender{   
    [(UINavigationController*)self.parentViewController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

As I said, everything works fine but I think I am creating new instances of the GoalViewController each time I click to visit the screen.
The viewDidUnload method in the GoalViewController is never called so I think they are never being released and would eventually cause a crash. However I have not been able to crash it by switching pages many many many times.

I've been looking for samples to compare my code to others to see what I am doing wrong but so far everything I am doing looks to be the proper way to do this.

I think I am looking for a way to test if the goalViewController I pushed to is still open and switch to it instead of allocating a new one.

I would really appreciate some insight on this. 
Thanks, 
Greg

P.S.

I actually tried inserting this in the viewWillAppear methods.

```
`NSMutableArray *allControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]     initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    NSLog(@"Controllers: %@",allControllers);`
```

As I switch between the splash goal view, this is the output I get. Splash View ID remains contents but Goal View ID changes each time.

```
2011-11-21 01:14:51.388 Controllers: ("<SplashViewController: 0x64468c0>")
2011-11-21 01:14:51.389 Controllers: <SplashViewController: 0x64468c0>
2011-11-21 01:14:58.494 Controllers: <GoalViewController: 0x6458ad0>
2011-11-21 01:14:58.495 Controllers: (
    "<SplashViewController: 0x64468c0>",
    "<GoalViewController: 0x6458ad0>"
)
2011-11-21 01:15:06.898 Controllers: <SplashViewController: 0x64468c0>
2011-11-21 01:15:11.139 Controllers: <GoalViewController: 0x5771660>
2011-11-21 01:15:11.140 Controllers: (
    "<SplashViewController: 0x64468c0>",
    "<GoalViewController: 0x5771660>"
```

Thanks, Greg

Comment: Clearly you are allocating new instances each time you navigate...

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed creating a new controller each time you call

`[[GoalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GoalViewController" bundle:nil]`

What I would suggest doing instead is create your GoalViewController once, outside of your startButton method (like in your parent view controller's `viewWillAppear` method), and keep it as a member variable of the parent object.  You can then push and pop it to your heart's content and Goal View ID will remain the same pointer each time.

Don't forget to release your GoalViewController when the parent is dealloc'd or unloaded (not sure if you're using ARC or not).

Hope this info helps!

Comment: Thank You! This was driving me crazy! 
It works properly now. 

It is strange that nobody does it this way int he books and tutorials on multiview applications!

Comment: oh... one helpful hint here:  don't forget to "accept" any answers that work for you.  That helps to motivate people to want to help you out when you ask questions.